# Ada Core Libraries

Tags: ada

Can I obtain the source code for the core Ada libraries?

I'd like to see the implementation of Text_IO.Get_Imediate and a few other features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on a linux/unix type system, the ada libs will probably be in somewhere like :

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4/adainclude/
```

NOTE: The filenames here do not use the standard rules for filename/package association and There are many renames etc, so you may need to dig a lot to find actually what you are looking for.

Comment: Which is why I usually just let GPS do the declaration navigation for me :-)

Comment: And why I let emacs do the declaration navigation for me :)

Answer (score 2):

This is dependant on the compiler you use. Some are open source, others are not.

If you use GNAT: Yes, you can. Either download/install the source package from your package repository, or download it from AdaCore on their libre page: http://libre.adacore.com

Answer (score 2):

If you're using one of the GNAT GPL distributions from AdaCore, and editing with GPS, you can simply right-click on a package or subprogram and select "Go to body of ..." and it will navigate you right to it.